# Operation Not Permitted Rails AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been deploying my web app to aws. I was timing out to connecting to the site and I timed out. So I went into EC2 to see why it was giving me a time out . I got this error:

```
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:374:in `delete': Operation not permitted @ unlink_internal - /var/app/current/tmp/pids/server.pid (Errno::EPERM)

from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:374:in `check_pid!'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:278:in `start'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:9:in `require'
from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

what could be causing it and how can it be fixed.

Thanks In Advance,
Connor

Comment: Looking at line 374 of `rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb`, it appears that it's trying (and failing) to delete the expired pid file at `/var/app/current/tmp/pids/server.pid`. I suspect it's a permissions problem - that is, that whatever user owns the `/var/app/current` directory differs from the user you're trying to run `rails server` with. You could do `sudo rm /var/app/current/tmp/pids/server.pid` to remove the pid and try again. That being said, there are lots of things that could cause a timeout - security group, ELB, nginx configuration, etc.

Comment: thanks that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at line 374 of `rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb`, it appears that it's trying (and failing) to delete the expired pid file at `/var/app/current/tmp/pids/server.pid`. I suspect it's a permissions problem - that is, that whatever user owns the `/var/app/current` directory differs from the user you're trying to run rails server with. You could do `sudo rm /var/app/current/tmp/pids/server.pid` to remove the pid and try again.